# Is there a way to block outbound calls/SMS when the monthly minutes/SMS from my provider has ended?

Tags: android, bundle

Been searching for ages. This should be really basic functionality right? Yet all I can find is parental control/data usage blockers. I just need the most simple thing/app/extension: I know providers offer this (at a cost), but this should be able to be achieved clientside right? (I mean, you can litteraly delete the phone app for instance). Also I would really like it, so that it makes it impossible to call (no notification, just a killswitch)

in pseudocode:
If (minutes_used > minutes_in_bundle):
disable_calling
if (monthEnded = True)
minutes_used = 0

If there was one service that did this for both DATA/SMS/MINUTES that would be even better. I'd have to be able to set the data/minutes/sms and date at which my bundle refreshes.

I tried searching for an app like this. I am using my phone's data limiter, but that doesn't solve the minutes/sms problem.

Comment: Besides, no Root would be optimal, as it's virtually impossible to root my phone.

Answer (score -1):

Check Your Provider's Services: Start by checking if your mobile service provider offers any tools or services to help you manage your usage. Some providers may offer options to limit or block specific types of usage when you reach your limit.